# SQl query to sum-up amounts by month/year

Tags: sql-server

I have a table "TABLE" like this:

```
Date(datatime)
Paid(int)
```

I have multiple "Paid" amounts per month.
I would like to sum up the Paid amount per month/year.

So far this is what I tried but I get errors in EXTRACT and in MONTH and however I am far to get it done with the years.

```
SELECT 
     EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Period) AS reference_month
     , SUM(Paid) AS monthly_payments 
FROM Paid 
GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Period) 
ORDER BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Period)
```

I am not really handy at this and I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: What database engine (and version) are you using?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
select year(date) as y, month(date) as m, sum(paid) as p
from table
group by year(date), month(date)
```

Comment: It is working perfectly. Thanks a lot. I have now an excellent example to follow for the other queries I need.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT YEAR([Date]) AS [Year], MONTH([Date]) AS [Month], SUM(Paid) AS Total
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY YEAR([Date]), MONTH([Date])
```

You need to use square brackets around your objects name `[]` when you have named your object with sql server `key words`.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I understand what you saying. In this case I have used simple names in my question but the real name in the table are not Key Words. Good to know for the future. Thanks