# Repost : SQl query to sum-up amounts by month/year

Tags: sql, sql-server

[Repost link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20974383/sql-query-to-sum-up-amounts-by-month-year)

My query is

```
SELECT MONTH(now()) as m, SUM(total) as grandtotal
FROM tb
group BY YEAR(now()), MONTH(now())
```

I'm searching how to get total from this year and month, but my grandtotal is sum last year too. For example I have data year 2018 month 8 = 20 and year 2017 month 8 = 40..
it will sum all. so my total going to be 60 not 20.

[example sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2eac0d/3)

Comment: I have tagged with SQL Server, under the assumption that the link you posted uses that database.  If I'm wrong, then remove the tag, and tag with the correct database.

Comment: If you want to use `SUM` aggregate function use `group by` instead of `order BY `

Comment: explain your question bit more. With some sample data, your result and expected result. You can create sql fiddle as well. Then I will help you

Comment: Make it easy to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Based on answer from last time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20974383/sql-query-to-sum-up-amounts-by-month-year?answertab=votes#tab-top)

```
select year(date) as y, month(date) as m, sum(paid) as p
from table
where year(now()) = year(date) and month(now()) = month(date)
group by year(date), month(date)
```

Note that if your table definition is different, then the column names may also differ.

Answer (score 0):

Use only month in group by - it will give you total sum in month level but if you put year also in group by level then it will show year and month wise totalsum

```
SELECT MONTH(now()) as m, SUM(total) as grandtotal
FROM tb
group BY MONTH(now())
```

Comment: not work sir.. still get data from last year (2017).. im already use group by.

Answer (score 0):

You should group by your field's values, not by a constant.

```
SELECT MONTH(YourDateField) as m, SUM(total) as grandtotal
FROM tb
WHERE YEAR(YourDateField) = YEAR(now())
GROUP BY YEAR(YourDateField), MONTH(YourDateField)
```